# Preview unable to copy text

Tags: preview, mojave

After upgrading to macOS Mojave, I suddenly cannot select text to copy anymore in Preview.app.

I can highlight as normal and when the highlighting tool is active, I can select text but it immediately gets colored yellow once I "release the mouse" (before the update, there were two ways of coloring text yellow: **1.** Highlight text (making it blueish) and click the highlight tool, or **2.** Click the highlight tool and drag and select it).

Edit: It is as if what has happened is that I can no longer see which text I am selecting. I can apparently select text and copy it and I can paste it into other programs, I just cannot see what text I am selecting while doing it.

Comment: Your last sentence says that you had this problem before the upgrade so why does your first sentence say the upgrade caused the problem?

Comment: I totally see what you mean, Mark, I updated the text. Hopefully it is clear now.